# How to prevent database server from lagging when auto back up of data to backup DB is in progress?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a windows 2008 r2 server with MSSQL server running on it as our application's database server (we use it 24 hours). It has auto back up every midnight (as it is the time when less users are accessing it) and the users usually complain of lagging or the response from database is taking hours before they can retrieve data at the instance/period of time. And these past few days, it took them 5 hours waiting for the server to throw back data.

Having to consider the time of unresponsiveness of the server and the database auto backup, I think the latter causes the said unresponsiveness of the server. What you guys do you think?

And if that's the case, how can I prevent it from doing so. Certainly I cant stop the auto back up, so I am thinking of installing a separate LAN card connecting the main server to the back up server. Do you think it would work? Or do you have any workaround? Sorry, Im new to this please bear with me, but I am very willing to learn :) Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You'd be better asking this on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: the backup database process does has some disk io overhead but it should not slow down the query that much. You are sure it is due to the backup operations and not something else ?

Comment: What data do you have that indicates the backup process is causing slowdown? Are there other activities going on during that time causing users grief? Also, is it the same user or group of users that encounter the slowdown? Is it something unique to that group, such as regional issues or perhaps they're all connected to the same 10/100Mbps switch? Suggest you look into what else is happening to the DB and/or server during the slowdown periods. Also, provide details on your overall setup especially where the .bak files are stored and where your mdf/ldf files are stored.

Comment: Don't make any assumptions until you've collected some data. It sounds like you need a DBA to first identify the cause of the issue. It could be something completely unrelated (i.e. a backup of another system using up shared resources).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to split your backup into smaller volumes?

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO  
DISK = 'C:\Backups\file1.bak',  
DISK = 'C:\Backups\file2.bak',  
DISK = 'C:\Backups\file3.bak',   
DISK = 'C:\Backups\file4.bak'  
WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = 'Estimating  backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT
```

Comment: how will this help? You're still doing lots of reads on the DB and writes to wherever the backup file is stored.

Answer (score -1):

"Try splitting the database into smaller volumes. By default, backing up a database includes other files like config files and schemas. Go to Exchange System Manager (make sure it's installed on the backup server) and run NTBACKUP. Choose a folder to save the backup, and wait for the backup to finish running.
"